# why am i getting this error?? Syntax error on token "void", @ expected android programming

Tags: android, eclipse

please help me with the following code...
i am trying to make an android application and i get an error in the code when i try to create a function inside onCreate..
the need to create a function is to access buttons, labels and textboxes....
here goes my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final EditText player = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.player);
    final TextView plrlbl1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    final ImageButton imageButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    public void thisfunction()
    {

    }
}
```

please help me create a function inside of oncreate...
help appreciated

Comment: You can learn Java here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Next time try to make your question so it relates to everyone not just I have a problem and here is my code:).

Answer (score 8):

```
public void thisfunction()
    {

    }
```

you declare the `thisfunction()` inside the `onCreate()`. You should declare outside the `onCreate`. If you are having this kind of issue I recommend you to read a basic programming book.

Answer (score 3):

> please help me create a function inside of oncreate...

You can't, Java doesn't allow it. You have to declare it outside of `onCreate()`.

Comment: then please help me 
what if i want to access buttons and labels outside of onCreate??

Comment: Read [this article](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm) to learn about variable scope.

Comment: @user1478541 Look at the samples in your SDK directory, they will help you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The correct setup is something like this

```
public class MyActivity extended Activity {

private TextView myTextView;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate () ; 
        setContentView(R.layout.main) ; 

        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1) ; 

        myNewMethod() ; 
    }

    private void myNewMethod () {
        myTextView.setText("Hello world") ; 
    } 
}
```